# In igraph, which network specifications allow groups of nodes to have the same distribution?

Tags: r, igraph

I am currently trying to generate a network where the degree distribution has a large variance, but with a sufficient number of nodes at each degree. For example, in igraph, if we use the Barabasi-Albert network, we can do:

```
g <- sample_pa(n=100,power = 1,m = 10)
g_adj <- as.matrix(as_adj(g))
rowSums(g_adj)
  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [29] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
 [57] 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
 [85] 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

The above shows the degree on each of the 100 nodes. The problem for me is that I would like to only have 10-15 unique degree values, so that instead of having 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 at the end, we have instead, for example,  93 for each of the last 7 nodes. In other words, when I call

```
unique(rowSums(g_adj))
```

I'd like at most 10-15 values. Is there a way to "cluster" the nodes instead of having so many different unique degree values? thanks.

Comment: The first three lines of your code give a different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sample_degseq`: *Generate random graphs with a given degree sequence*. For instance,

```
degrees <- seq(1, 61, length = 10) # Ten different degrees
times <- rep(10, 10) # Giving each of the degrees to ten vertices
g <- sample_degseq(rep(degrees, times = times), method = "vl")
table(degree(g))
#  1  7 14 21 27 34 41 47 54 61 
# 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Note that you may need to play with `degree` and `times` as ultimately `rep(degrees, times = times)` needs to be a [graphic sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html).